# rows are interchanging in uitableview in iphone?

Tags: iphone

In my application i need to add contacts of users, for that i am using UITableview with sections. Each section may contains 2 or 3 rows.
 while the editing was completed and scrolling the table view to top, the rows are interchanging in between sections.
Actually In design part i have placed FirstName and LastName in first section and email in second section but they are interchanging as firstName, email as first section and LastName as second section . can any one help me to solve this.
Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:**

Please find the code snippet below.

the method CellForRowAtIndexPath:

```
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) 
    {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
        cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;



        if(indexPath.section == 0) 
        {

            if(indexPath.row == 0) 
            {
//content of first Name

                txtFieldFirstName = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 290, 24)];
                txtFieldFirstName.tag=1;
                //txtFieldFirstName.placeholder = @"First";
                txtFieldFirstName.delegate = self;
                txtFieldFirstName.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:16.0];
                [cell.contentView addSubview:txtFieldFirstName];
            }

            else if(indexPath.row == 1) {
            //content of last Name
            }
        }

        else if(indexPath.section == 1) 
        {

            if(indexPath.row == 0) {
//content of Phone No
            }

            else if(indexPath.row == 1) {
           //content of Mobile no
            }
```

this is how i am implementing my code. Please help me on this.

Comment: Take a good hard look at your `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method.  Your table will display exactly what you return from that method.

Comment: Post the code from your cellForRowAtIndexPath method. It sounds like you are not using the sections or dequeueing the cells properly.

Comment: the problem is probably in your tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath: delegate method - where you fill the cells with data, but without seeing the code no one would able to help you.

Answer (score 2):

You are doing everything inside

```
if (cell == nil)
```

This code is only executed when you first create a cell. If the table view returns a cell that has already been created, cell != nil so the code is not executed.

You should only perform base configuration inside cell == nil, everything else should be done afterwards. You may need to have different reuse identifiers for cells in different sections if the layout is not the same.

Comment: See duncan babbage's answer, it's better than mine!

Answer (score 2):

The issue is that your cells are being reused, and they are carrying with them the values from the *previous* contact. It may look like the rows are interchanging between sections, but actually they are interchanging between *contacts*.

This sets the cell content outside of the `if (cell == nil)` so would address the issue in many cases:

```
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) 
{
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
}

if(indexPath.section == 0) 
{
    if (indexPath.row == 0) 
    {
        //content of first Name
        txtFieldFirstName = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 290, 24)];
        txtFieldFirstName.tag=1;
        //txtFieldFirstName.placeholder = @"First";
        txtFieldFirstName.delegate = self;
        txtFieldFirstName.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:16.0];
        [cell.contentView addSubview:txtFieldFirstName];
    }

    else if (indexPath.row == 1) {
        //content of last Name
    }
}

else if(indexPath.section == 1) 
{

    if(indexPath.row == 0) {
        //content of Phone No
    }

    else if(indexPath.row == 1) {
        //content of Mobile no
    }
}
```

However, if some cell properties are set on some occasions, and only others are used on other occasions, you may need to explicitly set the unused cell properties to nil in each case so that they do not carry over values from the previous contact they displayed, then they are reused in the dequeue process.

Answer (score 1):

Actually this is happening due to reuse identifier  of your table cell

Try below Code

```
NSString *CellIdentifier=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"cell%d",indexPath.section];
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) 
{
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];            
}
```

Comment: This will prevent the tableView from reusing any cells (except for the particular cell for the row), which could cause poor scrolling performance and unnecessary memory use.

Comment: @jrturton is that fine  my updated code as i have remove indexpath.row in CellIdentifier string                           i just need to ask because in my one of app cell are getting duplicate in normally way of defining the cell

Comment: Yeah, that's ok - that will reuse cells within a section. If the cells are different between sections, that's what you want.